# better approach of finding a variable is function?

Tags: javascript

Which one is better approach to find whether a variable is of type function

```
typeof(methodName) == typeof(Function)
```

or

```
typeof methodName === 'function'
```

Comment: Heres a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/typeof-string-vs-typeof) with some ways to determine if a variable is of type `"function"`

Answer (score 5):

There are two things going on here:

1. Parentheses — `typeof` is an operator, not a function, don't use them
2. Comparing to `'function'` or `typeof Function` (which will always return `'function'` unless someone is screwing around and overwriting native objects). Use the string, it requires less work and isn't subject to the aforementioned screwing around.

i.e. Use:

```
typeof methodName === 'function'
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution, the one which you'd find for example in jQuery source code ([example](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L408)), is the second one :

```
typeof value === 'function'
```

It's faster than the first one, as you don't need to call a second `typeof` and there's simply no reason to use the first one as [ECMAScript specifies that it has to be "function"](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The second one has **better performance** and used in many javascript library

Comment: @dystroy There was a comment before stating the first one has the better performance.. I guess he deleted the comment as well as his answer. He was lead to the conclusion by wrong code in his [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/ysuAs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the better approach

```
if (typeof methodName === 'function') {
   // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand. So this is correct -

```
typeof methodName === 'function'
```

See also: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)